# Ansible ad-hoc command with direct host specified - no hosts matched

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running a 16.04 Ubuntu desktop machine using VirtualBox. This VM has Ansible 2.4.0 installed. I am trying to run an ad-hoc ansible command just to prove it works (I am doing an online course). To simulate a small server farm, I use lxc (linux containters) and have three of them running:

```
root@tomasz-VirtualBox:/home/tomasz/ansible# lxc-ls --fancy
NAME STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4       IPV6 
db1  RUNNING 0         -      10.0.3.248 -    
web1 RUNNING 0         -      10.0.3.110 -    
web2 RUNNING 0         -      10.0.3.226 -
```

I can SSH to any of these servers, however when I try to run a one-off ansible command, for example:

```
root@tomasz-VirtualBox:/home/tomasz/ansible# ansible 10.0.3.248 -m ping -u ubuntu
```

I get the following errors, that no inventory has been matched:

```
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 10.0.3.248

 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

I am puzzled, to be honest, and as an Ansible novice, I have no idea how to move this forward. Seems such a simple issue, have not come across any similar thing here on stackoverflow. Many thanks for any hints!

Comment: _I am doing an online course_. Is there a chapter called `inventory` in that course?

Comment: Yes, there is, but in this very example I am running a one-off Ansible command for a specific host and as you can see I provide this host's IP address directly in the command. In this very case, according to my understanding, the inventory file is irrelevant.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think I am following the same tutorial, is it from Packt, and the instructor name is Dave?

Comment: Yup, that was the one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I provide this host's IP address directly in the command. In this very case, according to my understanding, the inventory file is irrelevant.

Wrong. You specify [host pattern](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html), which should match hosts in your inventory. Inventory is a must for Ansible.

There's an option to specify "inline" inventory. For your case:

```
ansible all -i '10.0.3.248,' -m ping -u ubuntu
```

in this example: host pattern is `all`, inventory is a list of a single host `10.0.3.248`.
Note comma at the end – it is important, this way Ansible understand that it is inline inventory, and not path to file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is a pity I can't paste in here a screenshot. I would like to show you, that the guy who runs that course (tutoriaLinux YT channel) does exactly the thing I was asking about. He enters this: ansible 10.0.3.248 -m ping -u ubuntu and gets the Ansible ping response.

Comment: for this exact command to work, you should have inventory defined.

Comment: Also, in the host pattern section of the Ansible documentation, it says: 
It is also possible to address a specific host or set of hosts by name:

one.example.com
one.example.com:two.example.com
192.0.2.50
192.0.2.*

Which, with all due respect, seems to be in the contrary to what you wrote.

Comment: If you don't believe me, you may want to believe Ansible: it gave you 4 warning messages about wrong inventory setup. It is possible to address a specific host **from inventory**, not arbitrary host by ip address. Please browse through official [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. What I learned is that if you set the inventory value in the ansible.cfg file, then you do not need to use -i flag, as ansible looks by default to the inventory file specified in ansible.cfg. So I was able to eventually see what I want:

`tomasz@tomasz-VirtualBox:~/ansible_code$ ansible 10.0.3.48 -m ping
 10.0.3.48 | SUCCESS => {
   "changed": false, 
   "failed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}`

Comment: "omasz@tomasz-VirtualBox:~/ansible_code$ ansible 10.0.3.48 -m ping 10.0.3.48 | SUCCESS => { "changed": false, "failed": false, "ping": "pong" }"
Hi Tomas, I already have my inventory declared in the ansible.cfg file, but each time I run the ping command, I get a failed message. How did you setup the ssh-rsa? as a normal user or sudo?