# How to Skip hosts repository and specify host Runtime in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I do not wish to specify any hosts file to ansible-playbook command.

```
ansible-playbook site.yml  -e "source_host=mymac1 source_file=myfile1"
```

My site.yml looks like this:

more site.yml

```
---

- hosts: "{{ source_host | default('my_pc')}}"
  user: weblogic
```

However, I get the following error:

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all
>
> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
>
> PLAYBOOK: site.yml
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** 2 plays in site.yml  [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern,
>   ignoring: mymac1

Can you please suggest how can i pass any host to my playbook without having to maintain and host respository with all the host information

I am on ansible version 2.3.1.0

Answer (score 4):

You can use inline inventory:

playbook.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=hello
```

command:

```
ansible-playbook -i 'mymac1,' -e source_file=myfile1 playbook.yml
```

note comma after hostname.

Also see: [Ansible ad-hoc command with direct host specified - no hosts matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592141/ansible-ad-hoc-command-with-direct-host-specified-no-hosts-matched/44592407#44592407)

Comment: I have two play inside my playbook so it has two  -hosts: . How can i make sure the first - hosts: gets  source_host=mymac1 and the second - hosts: gets dest_host=mymac2 which will be passed using the -e:  ansible-playbook site.yml  -e "source_host=mymac1 source_file=myfile1 dest_host=mymac2"

Comment: The first host will be the host of the source of the file while the second host will be the destination where it will be copied ... hence two hosts

Comment: Try `all[0]` and `all[1]` and `-i 'srchost,desthost'` (but I'm not sure, this is rather uncommon scenario).